# My strdup in ASM

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm, x86-64, glibc

Hello every body for my school i have to do my own strdup function in ASM [intel] [NASM].

I have e strange problem ...

In my code if I `call _malloc`

My code segfault with this error :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fff849612da in stack_not_16_byte_aligned_error () from /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
```

I don't understand why because In the section .text I said `extern _malloc`

Some one have an idee why I got this mistake ? :)

This is my code :

```
section .text
     global _ft_strdup
     extern _strlen
     extern _malloc
     ;  extern _ft_memcpy

_ft_strdup:
     call _strlen           ;rax = len of str
     mov r8, rdi            ;r8 = str = src
     inc rax                ;rax++
     ;  mov r9, rax         ;len of dest with '\0'
     mov rdi, rax           ;to send the len for malloc
     call _malloc           ;rax = ptr of dest
     ;  cmp rax, 0          ;malloc failled
     ;  jle _error_malloc
     ;  mov rdi, rax        ;malloc param 1 of ft_memcpy
     ;  mov rsi, r8         ;str in param 2 of ft_memcpy
     ;  mov rdx, r9         ;len of str with '\0' param 3 of ft_memcpy
     ;  call _ft_memcpy     ;call ft_memcpy
     ret
_error_malloc:
     xor rax, rax           ;return NULL
     ret
```

All functions start with `ft_`are the same than the libc Thx all

Comment: As for a possible hint about your problem, don't you wonder what `stack_not_16_byte_aligned_error` might mean? Perhaps you should start looking at how you set up your stack frames?

Comment: Fuz's answer is correct. As an experiment you can try to align the stack to a 16 byte boundary by simply pushing any value on the stack and popping it off at the end. For example as the first instruction in `_ft_strdup` put `push rbp` and then just before each `ret` put `pop rbp`.

Comment: Fuz and Michael Petch, I don't have segfault anymore, it's look find I keep checking thx  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error message indicates that you called `malloc` with an insufficiently aligned stack. The SysV-ABI for amd64 mandates that the stack is aligned to 16 bytes on function call.

In your own code, you can ensure this by making sure that you always push an even number of quadwords onto the stack and remember that on entry, the stack is misaligned by 8 bytes due to the return address being on the stack already.

Without seeing your source code it is hard to give more specific help.